# How to add SQL Server plugins to Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis, ssas

I have a SQL Server 2008 database which is located on a distant server (I have full access to this server however).
On my computer I have Visual Studio 2008 installed, and I need to load a solution which contains projects that have been created using plugins from SQL Server.
Those plugins are :
- SQL Server Analysis Services
- SQL Server Integration Services
- SQL Server Reporting Services

My question is: Is there a way to only install those plugins on my computer without installing the full Sql Server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the installation media for SQL Server, during the installation process it lets you pick and choose which options to install.  For example yesterday I installed SQL Server Management Studio...and that was it, off a standard SQL Server install disc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143708.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143708(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks Albert, it worked !

For the records, I had to install the Management Studio (I choose the complete one).